# conversion of SQL IN clause to multile ORs

Tags: algorithm

I have a string "VAR1 = ABCD AND VAR2 IN ('AB' , 'CD' , 'EF')"

I want to convert that into something like this

VAR1 = ABCD AND (VAR2 ='AB' OR VAR2= 'CD' OR VAR3 =  'EF')

what is the best method to handle this via an algorithm ?

Comment: Which language do you want to use? Do you know how recursive descent parsers work?

Comment: I use LL1 grammar (non recursive) , I use assembler language so non-recursive is better choice for me.  i am using    
E    -> T ''
A    -> + T A 
A    -> ''     
T    -> F B    
B    -> * F B
B    -> ''     
F    -> V G   
G    -> O  
O    -> #    
F    -> ( E ) for boolean parser but i am not sure how to fit that for IN clause